# i'm getting psycopg.OperationalError when i start the docker container, with flask and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

I'm building a flask RESTful API using flask and using PostgreSQL database and I'm trying to dockerize the app using docker-compose and Dockerfile, but when i'm trying to run the containers i'm getting this error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/app/try_flask.py", line 12, in \<module\> conn=psycopg.connect("dbname=testing  user=postgres port=5432 password=postgres") File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 728, in connect raise ex.with_traceback(None) psycopg.OperationalError: connection is bad: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

**the app file
try_flask.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, json, jsonify
import psycopg 


app = Flask(__name__)

conn=psycopg.connect("dbname=testing user=postgres port=5432 password=postgres")


cur=conn.cursor()



@app.route('/business_table/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def insert_locations():
    if request.method=="POST":
        business_name=request.form["name"]
        category=request.form["category"]
        cur.execute("select exists(select name from public.business where name=%s)", (business_name,))
        row = cur.fetchone()[0]               
        if row ==False:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO business(name,category) VALUES(%s, %s) RETURNING business_id ",
            (business_name,category))
            row = cur.fetchone()[0] 
        else:
            return "already exists on the database"
      
        conn.commit()
                
        return f"business with {business_name} is added with id {row}"
    
    elif request.method=="GET":
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM business")
    
        business=[
                dict(business_id=row[0],name=row[1],category=row[2])
                for row in cur.fetchall()
            ]
        conn.commit()

        return jsonify(business)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

**docker-compose.yaml file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgis/postgis:15-3.3-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=testing
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  app:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    entrypoint: ["python", "try_flask.py","runserver"]
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc && pip install psycopg
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
```

the PostgreSQL container is running fine, but the problem is on the python container, I have tried with these files but always the same error it seems a connection problem, any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the hostname for the Postgres container when you make the database connection. Otherwise, it defaults to `localhost`.

Since you're using Docker Compose, the hostname in the network that Docker creates is the name of the service, i.e. `postgres` in your case.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/.

Comment: sorry can you please give me more details i didn't understand what you mean or what to do

Comment: I'm not at s computer right now, so writing code is tricky (I'll edit when I can). When you call `psycopg.connect`, you need to specify the hostname, which should be `postgres`. Do you understand that with the code as you have written it, it's trying to connect to a database running on the same host (i.e. container) as your application?

Comment: yes i got it now and fixed it thank you very mush